# Installed software doesn't appear in Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: ubuntu-budgie

I am new to Ubuntu Budgie. I have installed Skype from the Software Center but it is not appearing in the Budgie start menu. Can some one please help?

Answer (score 0):

To start Skype from the terminal run the following command:

```
snap run skype
```